# C# Model context has changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, unit-of-work

I have one Solution FooHQ that contains:

FooModel - Code First

FooService - A service that uses the FooModel

FooWebsite - A Website that consumes the FooService and the FooModel

ALL works!

I just created a FooWebsiteAgain

I referenced up the FooService and FooModel and whamoo.....

The model backing the 'FOOContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)

Funny thing, if i step through in debugger and force it to navigate the UnitOfWork context and browse around....

```
using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork()) <<Debug here
   {
   var Customer = unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetCustomerByTN(TN);
   return Customer;
   }
```

... it wakes up and no error!

Please any ideas?

PS I am using EF 6.0.0

Comment: When you "browse around" in the debugger, do you actually activate a query?

Comment: child can not be displayed in results view @GertArnold but it does work as code in the next line...see above Customer is populated.

Comment: Where is your context and specifically which project(s) do you have migrations enabled in? If you're going to share an entity between multiple projects, then that entity should only be tracked in one, or even in a totally separate project specifically for the purpose, perhaps a class library. If you have multiple contexts referencing the same entity class, then *each* one will need to be migrated separately, which of course is impossible if the database is the same.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the context is also in the model along with migrations, the unit of work just derives the context.

Comment: Huh? You mean the context is defined in the same file as the model? That  doesn't really matter, although it at least says that they're both in same project, I guess. However, make sure that you don't have any other contexts in your other project(s) that might be referencing this same entity. The Visual Studio generators for things like controllers have a bad habit of creating contexts/DbSets for you, even when you don't want or need them.

Comment: Really, the only reason you'd be having this problem, assuming you've already applied all necessary changes to the table in question is if there's another context tracking the same entity, wanting you do a separate migration for it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, thats alot...ill have to further investigate....why does debugging wake up the context to start working though?

Comment: It's not that it's waking up; it's that the error is not related to anything that's going on in your service. The service has a reference to the correct context, and that context has been migrated properly, so that call works. However, project B has a different context that hasn't been properly migrated, so *project B* generates the exception. In other words, they aren't mutually exclusive. If you have multiple contexts hanging around one or more or both may be in use at the same time, and you'd only generate exceptions from one.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but when upgrading from EF 6.0 to the later 6.1.2 it works
Apparently all other projects where 6.1.0 and this confused EF